Supabase "No API key found in request."
I have a server where I self-host a Supabase service using Docker.
I've been testing it by working on a project for class using React together with Supabase. When making requests to the API, for some unknown reason, I don't get a response from the API. I've configured the API keys (ANON_KEY and SECRET_KEY) several times in the .env file, which I generated at https://supabase.com/docs/guides/self-hosting/docker#generate-api-keys, using a JWT Secret code that I personally wrote and also included in the .env file in the Supabase docker folder.

When creating my React project, I included these details in a .env.local file and used them to declare the connection with the Supabase library:
REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL=http://anthonyx82.ddns.net:8080
REACT_APP_ANON_KEY=My anon key

client.js:
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.REACT_APP_ANON_KEY

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey)
To test if the API was working, I tried signing up with a magic link:

Login:
import { useState } from "react";
import { supabase } from "../supabase/client";

function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({
        email: email,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="youremail@email.com"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

When running the application and testing with an email, I get the following error:

And when trying to access the API from the link, I get the following:

I want to point out that since I'm not working locally, I had to open port 8000, which I forwarded to 8080. It may be necessary to open some other port that I'm not aware of.
Thanks in advance!
PD: I was triying to do with supabase and it works but i want to work with autohost

i think .env.local is a nextjs thing but does not work with react out of the box, can you try renaming to .env.

Thats not the problem becouse react can read the file and when i do a console.log i get the values i think this is probably a fail configuration of supabase but i dont know what

Are you using NextJS

no im using react, but its equal to call the file .env or .env.local react read the file the same

Have you looked at the logs on your Supabase dashboard? It should give you more information about the cause of the error.

Yeah the problem was i need a smtp server for autohosting supabase
